# Unable to Save Performance Parameters in AUSampler

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to connect a performance parameter to control the amplifier gain of an AUSampler in AU Lab but I'm unable to save the parameter. When I click to another tab I get a message that says:

**You have a partially created performance parameter. Any changes will be lost. Would you like to continue editing your performance parameter or discard changes and leave the parameter editor?**

Does anyone know how to finalize the parameter? I believe I have connected it properly but it seems like I'm missing the last step. I've also noticed there is a gear icon in Apple's docs that shows the performance parameters that is not visible in my window. Could this be where you are supposed to save the parameter? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2331/_index.html

[image]

Comment: Kind of seems like a bug. I can't figure it out.  Maybe I just can't remember it being hard to find, but it really seems like a bug.

Comment: I was originally using AU Lab 2.2.2, I've now upgraded to 2.3.1 and still have the same issue although the settings icon is now visible like in the apple docs. Still can't save connections or parameters though.

Comment: Just checked this on another computer with a new install of 2.3.1 and got the same issue. Beginning to think AU Lab is broken...

Comment: File a radar with Apple.  I think it's broken too.  I've done it in the past and I don't remember anything like what's happening now.

Comment: Bug report submitted. I hope they fix it eventually : (

Comment: D'oh, just ran into this same problem. I wonder if loading an `.aupreset` with existing parameter connections will allow you to edit them? (Is that even where they get saved?)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to edit an existing instrument connection instead of creating a performance parameter.